# Vue js + Typescript Scroll to bottom of div when data changes

Tags: typescript, vue.js, scroll

I have a div that is updated with comments and I want when a new comment is added to scroll to the bottom of that div. I was trying to do something like this:

```
gotoBottom() {
    let content = this.$refs.commentsWrapper;
    content.scrollTop = content.scrollHeight
}
```

The div who contains the comments has the reference ref="commentsWrapper" and I get this error inside the function

```
Property 'scrollTop' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.
Property 'scrollTop' does not exist on type 'Vue'.
```

I was searching on internet and I think it's a Typescript error.
I tried to do this but it doesn't work either.

```
this.$refs.commentsWrapper['scrollTop'] = this.$refs.commentsWrapper['scrollHeight']
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with     let content = this.$refs.commentsWrapper.$el;

Comment: Per Raffobaffo's comment, see the [Vue Docs for ref](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref): `If used on a plain DOM element, the reference will be that element; if used on a child component, the reference will be component instance.`

Comment: @Raffobaffo thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Can you upvote my comment please, the correct answer has the same content of my comment :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change your code to

```js
gotoBottom() {
    let content = this.$refs.commentsWrapper as Vue;
    content.$el.scrollTop = content.scrollHeight;
}
```

Since `this.$refs.content` is a Vue component (in your case), you need to access `this.$refs.content.$el` to access the DOM element.